# Remove duplicate outputs from a dropdown list and separate by comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list

I have a list which has a list of several languages:

- German to English
- German to Spanish
- German to Chinese
- German to French
- English to Spanish
- English to French
- English to Greek
- English to Portuguese

How would you recommend doing this with javascript / jquery to display the list as the following:

German to English, Spanish, Chinese, French

English to Spanish, French, Greek, Portuguese

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Why not to declare two selections FROM and TO. First selection would have German, and Egllish, second all languages. When first selection is choosen, filter out its value in second selection.

Answer (score 0):

Parse each string. Build an associative array whose key is the first element in the string and the content an array, whose value is always appending the 3rd element in the string.

To print, foreach over all items in the associative array, printing the `$key` to the `implode`d elements of the array.